# Spark: How to avoid memory issues on large aggregation with distinct

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I start with a following an RDD that represent following data structure, user_id, product_id, bought/or not `RDD[(String, String, Int)]`

To understand the stats such as how many products that each user has bought I have done a following method:

```
  def userProductAggregation(rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, Int)]): RDD[(String, Long)] = {
    val productPerUserRDD = rdd.filter(_._3 == 1)
      .map { case (u, p, _) => (p, u) }
      .distinct(numPartitions = 5000)
      .map { case (p, _) => (p, 1L) }
      .reduceByKey(_ + _, numPartitions = 5000)
    return productPerUserRDD
  }
```

Problem is that I get Java Heap issue when I am trying this. My total input size is close to 500GB. In standalone I have set up my spark to `--driver-cores 8G --executor-memory 16G --total-executor-cores 80`. I think this should be plenty to do this job. Is there a better way to write this method? I thought my approach is very efficient but I am starting to question that. I have also tried to increase the number of partitions up to `8000` but still the issue was same.

Comment: are those all the transformations that you're doing over this RDD? Are there any other functions doing any other transformations/actions on the same RDD?

Comment: Yes thats the only transformation, once I get the RDD I do other transformation to the returned RDD but heap run out before getting to that part.

Comment: have you tried caching it before doing those transformations?

Comment: No, because I thought that would be a bad practice. Can you explain why that would be better? Just want to get a better understanding.

Comment: Transformations will be recalculated on each action call. Caching the RDD will help avoiding recalculating the transformations up to the caching point

Comment: Not sure if you solved this issue already, but if not, a few more information about how you are running this could be useful:
Are you running this locally or in a cluster?
If the latter, how much memory and storage have your machines? 
Which version of Spark are you using?
`80` executores-core seem to be a lot of cores per machine, have you tried with fewer?
You could try something like this (20-node cluster, 60GB mem, >250GB Storage):
`num-executors`: `20`
`executor-cores`: `4`
`driver-memory`: `25g`
`executor-memory`: `40g`
`spark.driver.maxResultSize`: `10g`